# How to get the js error stack in react-native release build and translate to exact file with sourcemap?

Tags: javascript, react-native, crash

All of these are done in debug build, it's very useful for debugging script error.

But I want this to be available in release build, instead of displaying a red alert view, I may save the error info and upload to my server, and analyze it offline.

How could this be done ?

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a